# “Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly”?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, http-put

I am facing the following issue while sending **PUT** request but **POST** request is working fine.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.d.MoveNext()

Actually I upgraded my **AspNet Core API** from **2.2** to **3.1** before upgrading it was working fine and content-length is in between 700-1800.
And my Program.cs file is as follows.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Setting the MinRequestBodyDataRate to null, request gets more time and return the same exception as above. Any suggestions or solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to set a brake point at your Action and see how fast the data becomes available? I know this seems obvious, but I think it helps if we know the basics are set up right.

Comment: Actually locally it is working fine, after uploading on server HttpPut causing the issue and everything else is working fine.